# How to colour a specific word in datagrid

Tags: livecode

How to colour a specific word in datagrid.The following code i tried but it's not working. How i change my code

```
set the backgroundcolor of "SHALU" of group "data" to orange
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

locate the word and use its position with `chars` similar to this

```
set the backgroundColor of char 20 to 22 of fld 1 to orange
```

or since it is a datagrid:

`set the htmltext of field 1 of group "datagrid 1"  to "<font bgcolor="&quote&"#FF0000"&quote&">test text"`

Comment: you are right, sorry. There does not seem to be an easy way as i thought. You can change the text color for the whole datagrid with

    `set the dgprop["text color"] of group "datagrid 1" to "red"`

but this does not work with one word:

  `set the dgprop["text color"] of word 3 of group "datagrid 1" to "red" `

So I think you have to try along the lines of html text and then put it into the datagrid with the colored background in html.

Comment: How to work this with html. please make me clear by proper codes

Comment: the following code changes the color of the first columns label: `set the htmltext of field 1 of group "datagrid 1"  to "<font color="&quote&"green"&quote&">test "`